# How to query an array of values within a JSONB field dictionary?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column that contains a dictionary which has a key that points to an array of string values. I need to query against that array.

The table (called "things") looks like this:

```
------------------
| my_column      |
|----------------|
| { "a": ["X"] } |
------------------
```

I need to write two queries:

Does the array contain value "X"?

Does the array not contain value "X"?

`my_column` has a non-null constraint, but it can contain an empty dictionary. The dictionary can also contain other key/value pairs.

The first query was easy:

```sql
SELECT * FROM things
  WHERE my_column -> 'a' ? 'X';`
```

The second one is proving to be more challenging. I started there with:

```sql
SELECT * FROM things
  WHERE NOT my_column -> 'a' ? 'X';
```

... but that excluded all the records that had dictionaries that didn't include key `'a'`. So I modified it like so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM things
  WHERE my_column -> 'a' IS NULL OR NOT
        my_column -> 'a' ? 'X';
```

This *works*, but is there a better way? Also, is it possible to index this query, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's any better way -- that honestly looks pretty straightforward to me.

As for indexing, there are a couple things you can do.

First, you can [index the jsonb field](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). Putting a GIN index on that field should help with any use of "exists"-type operators (like `?`).

If that isn't the solution you want for whatever reason, Postgres supports functional and [partial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) indexes. A functional index might look like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON things ( my_column -> 'a' );
```

(note: It looks like postgres is having trouble with that syntax, which might be a bug. The concept holds, though.)

A partial index would get even more specific, and could even look like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON things (my_column)
  WHERE my_column -> 'a' IS NULL OR NOT
    my_column -> 'a' ? 'X';
```

Obviously, that won't help for more general queries.

At a guess, indexing the whole column with a GIN index is the right way to go, or at least the right place to start.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. The error with your index creation is you needed 2 sets of parens, so:

```CREATE INDEX ON things (( my_column -> 'a' ));```